# How can I speed up an email-finding regular expression when searching through a massive string?

Tags: python, regex

I have a massive string. It looks something like this:

```
hej34g934gj93gh398gie foo@bar.com e34y9u394y3h4jhhrjg bar@foo.com hge98gej9rg938h9g34gug
```

Except that it's much longer (1,000,000+ characters).

My goal is to find all the email addresses in this string.

I've tried a number of solutions, including this one:

```
#matches foo@bar.com and bar@foo.com
re.findall(r'[\w\.-]{1,100}@[\w\.-]{1,100}', line)
```

Although the above code technically works, it takes an insane amount of time to execute. I'm not sure if it counts as catastrophic backtracking or if it's just really inefficient, but whatever the case, it's not good enough for my use case.

I suspect that there's a better way to do this. For example, if I use [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/0GBW2K/1) to only search for the latter part of the email addresses:

```
#matches @bar.com and @foo.com
re.findall(r'@[\w-]{1,256}[\.]{1}[a-z.]{1,64}', line)
```

It executes in just a few milliseconds.

I'm not familiar enough with regex to write the rest, but I assume that there's some way to find the @x.x part first and then check the first part afterwards? If so, then I'm guessing that would be a lot quicker.

Comment: Try `r'\b\w[\w.-]{0,99}@[\w.-]{1,100}'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - I'll have to test it more, but that seems to work reasonably well. Can you post it as an answer with an explanation of why it's better?

Comment: @Jan - According to regex101.com, that results in catastrophic backtracking.

Comment: @Jan - Sorry, I was testing it with my actual string. Here's a closer approximation: https://regex101.com/r/kb3XsX/1

Comment: @Pikamander2: I see, take @Wiktor's expression then. The problem is that `\S` contains far more characters than `\w`, so his expression is by far faster (but won't allow addresses like `-email@address.com` which may or may not be a problem. The address is totally valid but unlikely to occur.

Comment: @Jan - Is there really no way to "go backwards", though? My second expression above is insanely fast.

Comment: No, regex engine parses the string from left to right. When you use a word boundary, the Python `re` engine does some optimization, it only checks at word boundaries, and there are fewer locations for it to test. That is why word boundary makes matching quicker here.

Comment: Also, PyPi regex module might be faster here. Try.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - It turns out that the default regex engine (re) was the problem. Pip's regex module handles the original expression very quickly. Please post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: I posted a more or less complete answer with test times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [PyPi `regex` module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) by Matthew Barnett, that is much more powerful and stable when it comes to parsing long texts. This regex library has some basic checks for pathological cases implemented. The library [author mentions](https://bugs.python.org/issue2636#msg90954) at his post:

> The internal engine no longer interprets a form of bytecode but
>   instead follows a linked set of nodes, and it can work breadth-wise as
>   well as depth-first, which makes it perform much better when faced
>   with one of those 'pathological' regexes.

However, there is yet another trick you may implement in your regex: Python `re` (and `regex`, too) optimize matching at word boundary locations. Thus, if your pattern is supposed to match at a word boundary, always start your pattern with it. In your case, `r'\b[\w.-]{1,100}@[\w.-]{1,100}'` or `r'\b\w[\w.-]{0,99}@[\w.-]{1,100}'` should also work much better than the original pattern without a word boundary.

Python test:

```
import re, regex, timeit
text='your_long_sting'
re_pattern=re.compile(r'\b\w[\w.-]{0,99}@[\w.-]{1,100}')
regex_pattern=regex.compile(r'\b\w[\w.-]{0,99}@[\w.-]{1,100}')
timeit.timeit("p.findall(text)", 'from __main__ import text, re_pattern as p', number=100000)
# => 6034.659449000001
timeit.timeit("p.findall(text)", 'from __main__ import text, regex_pattern as p', number=100000)
# => 218.1561693
```

Comment: Thanks! The pip `regex` module handled the original expression very quickly compared to the built-in `re` module.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use regex on the whole string. Regex are slow. Avoiding them is your best bet to better overall performance.

My first approach would look like this:

- Split the string on spaces.
- Filter the result down to the parts that contain `@`.
- Create a pre-compiled regex.
- Use regex on the remaining parts only to remove false positives.

Another idea:

- in a loop....
- use `.index("@")` to find the position of the next candidate
- extend e.g. 100 characters to the left, 50 to the right to cover name and domain
- adapt the range depending on the last email address you found so you don't overlap
- check the range with a regex, if it matches, `yield` the match

Comment: The second idea was roughly what I had in mind for a fallback solution, but I'm surprised that there doesn't seem to be a pure regex solution here.

Comment: @Pikamander2 Regex are *slow*. Orders of magnitude slower than string operations like `.index()`. Slow enough to make it worthwhile fiddling with a little arithmetic in order to avoid having to run them on the entire input. The amount you can gain by optimizing the regex itself is limited.